# read JSON from file

Tags: jquery, json

Hello I have a json file that has the following data and  called textareasdata:

```
[
{"Select":"11","PhotoCount":"12"},
{"Select":"21","PhotoCount":"22"}
]
```

So I would like to display the first Select and PhotoCount in a div element in my html page, I'm using the following function :

```
function fncLoadData(){

        $.getJSON('textareasdata.json', function(data) {
                        //alert(data);
            $("#txtTextArea").html(data);


        });
}
```

It shows [object Object] on the alert box.
Please how can I do ,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
function fncLoadData() {
    $.getJSON('textareasdata.json', function(data) {
        var firstSelect = data.shift();
        $("#txtTextArea").html(firstSelect.Select + " " + firstSelect.PhotoCount);
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you everybody, this works :

    function fncLoadData() {
        $.getJSON('textareasdata.json', function(data) {
            var firstSelect = data.shift();
            $("#txtTextArea").html(firstSelect.Select + " " + firstSelect.PhotoCount);
        });
    }

but it gives me access to only the first row of the json file, now, how can I do to access the second row in my json file :  this one

    {"Select":"21","PhotoCount":"22"}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
[ // <-- array of
{"Select":"11","PhotoCount":"12"}, // <-- objects
{"Select":"21","PhotoCount":"22"}
]
```

So to get the first object, use [index] - arrays are zero indexed

```
data[0].Select  // get first select
data[0].PhotoCount  // get first photocount
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#yourDIV").html(data[0].Select+data[0].PhotoCount);
```